# Searching for "All Referenced Text Strings" in WinDBG

Tags: search, windbg, cracking, ollydbg

In Olly Dbg, there is an option to search for "All Referenced Text Strings." Is there a way to do something similar in WinDBG?

So far, I have tried the following:

```
s -[l4]sa 0x0 L?0xFFFFFFFF
```

This, however, returns a ton of garbage. Any ideas on how to reduce this to a more manageable list of strings (and maybe where they are referenced?) the way Olly does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have a look at [this book](http://books.google.de/books?id=aimxHAHHe1IC&pg=PA167&lpg=PA167&dq=windbg%20dpu&source=bl&ots=eFOf0FcUCi&sig=BHdnTYxxwm_OYzcMgoYLaWK-pO4&hl=de&sa=X&ei=dZS_T6iKJebN4QSbzvyFCg&ved=0CGAQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=windbg%20dpu&f=false) and try the suggested tips and tricks..

```
There are wonderful WinDbg commands dpu (UNICODE strings) and dpa (ASCII strings) and other d** equivalents like dpp....
```

Comment: Ok, this (http://windbg.info/doc/1-common-cmds.html) is much better.... and look for "Display referenced memory"

Comment: Only problem with this is that upon opening WinDBG, execution seems to begin in ntdll instead of my app, so doing this returns stuff in the 7xxxxxxx range instead of the 004xxxxx range that I am interested in. I would like to be able to search through the executable I opened rather than its dependencies.